# PCA all variables vs PCA subgroups

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I have about 600 variables (no response variable) and I would like to use PCA to reduce the number of dimensions (variables). After reduction, I only want to have 100 variables. One approach I can do is do PCA for the whole dataset with 600 columns and chose the top 100 princial components.

However, there are 5 subgroups of variables in the 600 variables (demographic, spending habit, etc...). Is there any theoretical benefit of doing PCA for variables in each subgroup, then keep the top 20 principal components, then combine the kept principal components (20 for each subgroup) to have 100 principal components in total?

Comment: Why are you performing PCA? What do you plan to do with the data / PCs?

Comment: I want to reduce the number of variables from 600 to 100 and use those 100 variables/principal components for further modeling (I don't know exactly what type of modeling for now)

Comment: Note that it is necessary to transform back the principal components if it's ever needed to make useful interpretation.